# How to set react state from local storage when rendering main component, using useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a logic that saves data to local storage, I found a way to get those data from local storage but it works only when I refresh , not when I render the component, I have a problem finding a way to inject local storage data when rendering the main component to the default state, my current implementation is wrong I am using reload function for that purpos which if something change and the user go back a page the data changes wont show unless the user reload the page....

```js
// Current implmntation works only when i maulay refresh or refresh using a funtion 
// Context API file ! 

let list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lst') || '[]');
const defaultState: StateInterface = {
 list : {
    items: list,
  } 
 }

 // Main component that i want the above state to be changes if there is data in LS 
const TrainingPlanner: React.FC = () => {
  const context = useContext(itemsContext);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {}, []);
  const [list, setList] = React.useState(false);
  return (
<div>
list
</div>
};

export default TrainingPlanner;
```

Comment: [There's a hook for this.](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the [`useLocalStorage`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useLocalStorage.md) hook implemented in react-use

```js
const [list, setList, removeList] = useLocalStorage('lst', []);
```

Comment: You should probably explain how to use it in your answer.

Comment: Updated with usage

Comment: @miklando can I set the whole thing if found at once ? insted on single item ? i mean what if i have 4 ls values like list, items, users ?

Comment: @Richardson I'm not exactly sure what you mean. You could use an object as the local storage value and store several lists inside it if you wanted. I also see you're using a context but didn't attach the code.

Comment: @miklando lets say the ls object looks like {items : [array of times ], list : [array of items]} and I want to add both of them at once to the state instead of doing that in a singular way.

Comment: @Richardson it's usually not the best to save large objects into state values and better to handle them in something like Redux or a Context but you could load them both in a useEffect and do a single setState call at the end with the composed object

Comment: @miklando I am actually want to send the whole ls object using reducer but there i cannot find a way to get the whole ls object and parseit. i am using windows.localstorage

Answer (score 0):

you can pipe with a helper function

```
const getListFromLS = () => {
    //returns null if no items found.
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lst')) || [];
}
```

and in your setState

```
const [list, setList] = useState(getListFromLS());
```